# Service that calculate distance and speed from Location in Android

Tags: android, service

I am developing GPS Android app. I have an Activity that show the information a Service get and calculate from Location.

All works fine until the Activity is closed. In this scenario the Service go on running but all data is reset: the elapsed time, speed, distance...  So is like I started from begining. I figure out that is because that service was running in Activity Thread.

What can I do? My Service should go on calculating distance, speed and so on although Activity was closed so when Activity is open again it should show updated data that has been calculated by the service in background.

The service only can be stopped by the Activity so the user has to open the activity to close the service.

I tried to use static variables at Service but does not work. For example, if Service has been calculated 30 meters distance and saved it in a static variable when Activity is stopped the service go on running but the variale distance is 0 instance of 30.

PD/ All I liked to achieve is the same that you can see in apps like Strava or Runtastic where the user can closed the Activity but the service go on working and when you open again the app you can see the data the service was calculating.

Comment: you'll need to provide more details to get a proper response. your service can get stopped and restarted at anytime and you would lose data if it's not persisted, so using a database sounds like a viable option. if it's simple data structures, even a shared preference file would work.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thank you for your advice. I was thinking in SharedPreferences too but I do not know if this approach is really a "professional" option one or there are better options.